# Temporary view for multiple statements in a procedure?

Tags: sql-server, view, common-table-expression, temp-tables

Is there a way to create a temporary view, similar to a CTE, but which can be used in multiple statements within a stored procedure? Something like this:

```
create procedure dosomething as 
begin
    create view #temp as select ... ;

    Statement 1 with #temp;
    Statement 2 with #temp;
    Statement 3 with #temp;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put the view's results into a temporary table e.g.,

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
INTO #TempTable
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

That should do what you need, without needing to run the view many times?

Comment: For added speediness, remember you can put indexes (including a PK with clustered index) on temporary tables. It can be useful if doing many queries using the table as it can speed up joins by pre-sorting and/or allowing index seeks.